# XML message received on ESB contains <ns2: prefix in tags

Tags: xml, namespaces, jaxb, prefix, unmarshalling

I created a simple application which picks up file from folder, jaxb unmarshalls it into class and send it to service. On service-side, message doesn't come in plain format:

Example:

`<Source>
</Source>`

, but with prefix ns2: (i suppose this is refference to some namespace)

Example

```
<ns2:Source>
```

What am I doing wrong? Is problem in unmarshalling or on service-side?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873429/controlling-namespace-prefixes-in-jaxb