# Can't see namespace prefixes in XML file

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling

I marshall some object but the problem is JAXB writes default namespace prefixes instead of predefined ones. Is there any idea what can cause this problem?

What I expect to see;

```
<xbrli:entity>
....
```

What I got;

```
<ns3:entity>
....
```

I generated all classes(including package-infos)

example package-info;

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance",
    xmlns = {
@XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance", prefix = "xbrli2")
},
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package org.xbrl._2003.instance;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873429/controlling-namespace-prefixes-in-jaxb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) does not offer a standard way to specify the namespace prefix used.

### Extension - `NamespacePrefixMapper`

For the JAXB reference implementations and recent versions of EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) you can use the `NamespacePrefixMapper` extension to control the namespace prefixes used.

**MyNamespaceMapper**

```
import com.sun.xml.internal.bind.marshaller.NamespacePrefixMapper;
//import com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.NamespacePrefixMapper;

public class MyNamespaceMapper extends NamespacePrefixMapper {

    private static final String FOO_PREFIX = ""; // DEFAULT NAMESPACE
    private static final String FOO_URI = "http://www.example.com/FOO";

    private static final String BAR_PREFIX = "bar";
    private static final String BAR_URI = "http://www.example.com/BAR";

    @Override
    public String getPreferredPrefix(String namespaceUri, String suggestion, boolean requirePrefix) {
        if(FOO_URI.equals(namespaceUri)) {
            return FOO_PREFIX;
        } else if(BAR_URI.equals(namespaceUri)) {
            return BAR_PREFIX;
        }
        return suggestion;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getPreDeclaredNamespaceUris() {
        return new String[] { FOO_URI, BAR_URI };
    }

}
```

**Specifying the `NamespacePrefixMapper`**

Below is an example of how the `NamespacePrefixMapper` is set on the `Marshaller`.

```
    Marshaller m = ctx.createMarshaller();
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    try {
        m.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.namespacePrefixMapper", new MyNamespaceMapper());
        //m.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper", new MyNamespaceMapper());
    } catch(PropertyException e) {
        // In case another JAXB implementation is used
    }
```

### Extension - Leveraging `@XmlSchema`

EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) and recent versions of the JAXB reference implementation will use the namespace prefixes defined on the package level `@XmlSchema` annotation.

```
@XmlSchema(
    elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
    namespace="http://www.example.com/FOO",
    xmlns={
        @XmlNs(prefix="", namespaceURI="http://www.example.com/FOO")
        @XmlNs(prefix="bar", namespaceURI="http://www.example.com/BAR")
    }
)
package blog.prefix;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

### For More Information

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/11/jaxb-and-namespace-prefixes.html