# How do I add attributes to a root element when the class is generated by JAXB?

Tags: spring-mvc, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I'm developing a REST API that uses Spring MVC. The objects I consume and produce are generated (using JAXB) from NCPDP (http://www.ncpdp.org/) XSDs. I have everything working when requests come in, but I'd like to add additional attributes to the root element on outgoing requests.

Right now, my outgoing response looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<transport:Message xmlns:transport="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/transport">
    <transport:Header>
        ...
    </transport:Header>
    <transport:Body>
        <transport:Status>
            <transport:Code>010</transport:Code>
            <transport:Description>OK</transport:Description>
        </transport:Status>
    </transport:Body>
</transport:Message>
```

And it should look as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<transport:Message xmlns:transport="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/transport" xmlns:datatypes="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/datatypes" 
    xmlns:script="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/script" xmlns:structures="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/structures" 
    xmlns:pa-structures="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/pa-structures" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    StructuresVersion="v2014041" ECLVersion="v2014041" DatatypesVersion="v2014041" PA-StructuresVersion="v2014041" 
    TransactionVersion="v2014041" TransportVersion="v2014041" TransactionDomain="SCRIPT">
  <transport:Header>
    ...
  </transport:Header>
  <transport:Body>
    <transport:Status>
      <transport:Code>010</transport:Code>
    </transport:Status>
  </transport:Body>
</transport:Message>
```

I don't believe I need all the namespaces defined (since they're not used), but I do need the StructuresVersion and all other attributes. Is there a way to modify my bindings.xjb to include these attributes? Or do I have to copy the generated code into my source tree and add annotations to do this?

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: Does your schema declare these atributes? Please post the schema fragment declaring `transport:Message`.

Comment: Yes, it does. I never bothered to look before I posted this question. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: No problem, this happens. I'll post this as an answer in order to avoid misleading new users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since these attribute are declared in your XML schema, you should be getting appropriate properties in your schema-derived code.

It actually does not matter if this is a root element or some child element. Please re-check the generated code, look for something like `getStructuresVersion()`. So you don't need to do anything.

As for the namespaces, you will get them automatically declared, when you marshal. But you may first get them declared as `ns0`, `ns1` etc. which is not very nice in terms of readability. Please see the following question:

[Controlling namespace prefixes in JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873429/controlling-namespace-prefixes-in-jaxb)

(the question itself, not the answers) for information on how to control these prefixes with a custom prefix mapper or [this post](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jaxb-and-namespace-prefixes) by Blaise Doughan.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't even think to look and see if I could call message.setStructuresVersion('v2014041'). I have the prefixes figured out thanks to a bindings.xjb - https://gist.github.com/mraible/abad8d78c1f053ec686b.

Comment: @MattRaible This is good with `http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/namespace-prefix` what you did there. Please consider writing a Q&A post on that, this will be valuable for other users as well.