# How to remove the default root element namespace prefix from XML generated using JAXB

Tags: spring-mvc, jaxb

I am using JAXB with spring-mvc framework to generate XML. This is the example of root element:

```
<ns2:urlset xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com">
```

However, this is what I want (no XML namespace prefix `ns2`):

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.example.com">
```

I've tried to use the following `package-info.java` to remove the default prefix `ns2`.

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(  
    namespace = "http://www.example.com",   
    xmlns = {@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.example.com", prefix="")},  
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED)  
package com.example.code
```

The prefix can be changed to other value (than `ns2`) if I set `prefix` to another string. But the prefix can't be removed by setting `prefix` value to "". It still shows the default one `ns2`. Is there a way to remove the default prefix `ns2`?

Another question is that if the `standalone` attribute in the header of the XML can be removed too? If so, can it be done through `package-info.java`?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

package-info.java

```
    @XmlSchema(
    namespace="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9", 
    elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.example.model;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
```

XmlUrlSet.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name = "urlset", namespace = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9")
public class XmlUrlSet {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

If [@alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13483425/1126526) did not work, you may have found a bug (at least, I think, that it is one) in the reference implementation of JAXB. I just had the same problem - if I added a JaxbElement to my model-class, the JAXB RI started ignoring my default namespace. I could not find another solution than switching to Eclipse MOXy (without any other modification) and it worked.  (Caution: watch out for [another bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808921/jaxb-qualified-attributes-disables-default-namespace-xmlns) in moxy)

Also for your second question, use this:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(...);
Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaler();
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
```

Comment: I believe there may be a possibility of a bug. But then I am writing this out in 2019 when java is supposedly god of programming languages. How to get rid of prefixes from the root element name in generated xml <vc:My_File_Header>...</vc:My_File_Header>

Answer (score 1):

Every Java object and nested field therein that will be written as an XML element, has a namespace associated with it. If the marshaller detects more than one namespace in the object tree being marshalled, it will add appropriate namespace prefixes to disambiguate them in the marshalled XML.

The following discussion is applicable to Java 1.6 and above.

## [Example 1](https://www.ideone.com/JcKTab)

---

Instances of the class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Message")
class Message {
  @XmlAttribute(name = "Version")
  public int getVersion() { return 1; }
}
```

will get serialized as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Message Version="1"/>
```

because the XML message has a single element (`Message`), with the default namespace (`""`).

## [Example 2](https://www.ideone.com/Zb1zRl)

---

Instances of the class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Message", namespace = "http://example.com/schema/message")
class Message {
  @XmlAttribute(name = "Version")
  public int getVersion() { return 1; }
}
```

(custom namespace added to `@XmlRootElement`) will get serialized as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Message xmlns="http://example.com/schema/message" Version="1"/>
```

because the XML message still has a single element only (`Message`), albeit with a custom namespace (`http://example.com/schema/message`) instead of the default one.

## [Example 3](https://www.ideone.com/4WpVi6)

---

Instances of the class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Message", namespace = "http://example.com/schema/message")
class Message {
  @XmlElement(name = "Version")
  public int getVersion() { return 1; }
}
```

(`@XmlAttribute` changed to `@XmlElement`) will get serialized as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:Message xmlns:ns2="http://example.com/schema/message">
    <Version>1</Version>
</ns2:Message>
```

because the XML message now has two elements (`Message` and `Version`), with different namespaces (`http://example.com/schema/message` and `""` respectively). Therefore, the marshaller is forced to disambiguate the two elements through their own namespaces.

## [Example 4](https://www.ideone.com/9iyxe9)

Instances of the class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Message", namespace = "http://example.com/schema/message")
class Message {
  @XmlElement(name = "Version", namespace = "http://example.com/schema/message")
  public int getVersion() { return 1; }
}
```

(custom namespace added to `@XmlElement`) will get serialized as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:Message xmlns:ns2="http://example.com/schema/message">
    <Version>1</Version>
</ns2:Message>
```

because although the XML message has two elements (`Message` and `Version`), they share the same namespace (`http://example.com/schema/message`). Therefore, there is no longer any ambiguity in deciding which namespace each element belongs to, hence, only one namespace declaration in the resultant XML.